# javascript function is reset everytime I call a livewire action

Tags: javascript, laravel-livewire

What I'm trying to do is setting 'active' on the class of the button that was clicked, and on every other button remove the class 'active' if it was present in it, problem is everytime I click the button that isn't active, it gives the attribute 'active' and removes it from the other one for a second and then returns everything to how it was before I clicked.

My view:

```
    <ul class="nav" id="myDIV">

            <li class="nav-item active" wire:click="$emit('PaginaPrincipal')">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#" onclick="event.preventDefault();" >
                    <i class="nc-icon nc-icon nc-paper-2"></i>
                    <p>Página Principal</p>
                </a>
            </li>


            @foreach ($titulos as $titulo)

            <li class="nav-item" wire:click="ViewNiveis">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#" onclick="event.preventDefault();" >
                    <i class="nc-icon nc-icon nc-paper-2"></i>
                    <p>{{ $titulo }}</p>
                </a>
            </li>

            @endforeach
```

My javascript:

```
var header = document.getElementById("myDIV");
    var btns = header.getElementsByClassName("nav-item");
    for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++)
     {
        btns[i].addEventListener("click", function()
        {
            var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
            current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
            this.className += " active";
        });
    }
```

After some trial and error I have found out that if I remove the livewire action that is inside the foreach it stops resetting itself, is there any way to stop it from resetting itself while still keeping my livewire action?

Thanks in advance.

Update:

I have tried other javascript functions online to see if the problem was some confusion between javascript and livewire, but it stills produces the same error.

Answer (score 0):

try btns[i] instead of this in the event listener code.

You could also change the previous code to document.querySelector(‘.active’) instead of selecting all elements with the class name and then using index of 0 to select the first active element.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I have tried with the btns[i] instead of this but it doesn't insert the active class on the clicked button and it will still remove active from the other button, the resetting thing still happens as well. The second part I can't seem to replicate it, what do you mean by using index of 0? Could you give me an example? I'm not really that fluent in javascript by the way.